# Mongo merge documents by id in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In the `contacts` collection

```
{ 
    _id: "uabfyuagfyugdfudf",
    "dueDays": "30",
    "manufacturerId": 527,
    "name": "Dan Bilzarian",
    "phoneNumber": "",
    "status": "active",
}
```

In the `orders` collection

```
{
   _id: "kjabsuhabhd",
   "contactId": "uabfyuagfyugdfudf",
   "orderLines": [
     {"productId": "p1", "price": 24 }
   ]
}
```

What's the most effective way in mongodb to list 30 orders and for each order to fetch the customer document with `[name, phoneNumber, status]`?
`$aggregate` was really slow.

Ideal result

```
{
   _id: "kjabsuhabhd",
   "contactId": "uabfyuagfyugdfudf",
   "contact": { "name: "name": "Dan Bilzarian", "status": "active", "phoneNumber": "" },
   "orderLines": [
     {"productId": "p1", "price": 24 }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can we see the query that was too slow?  How are you selecting the 30 orders to return?

Comment: It's slow because I'm using 2 calls

`products.list({ docType: 'product' }).limit(20)`

and then `contacts.list({ _id: { $in: contactIds}})` and match with products